# Extraer datos de objeto en JavaScript

Tags: javascript, objeto, javascript-objeto, payload

Tengo un problema extrayendo cosas de un objeto

```
   var payload = {
                "ticket1":{"numero":1, "escritorio":1},
                "ticket2":{"numero":1, "escritorio":2},
                "ticket3":{"numero":1, "escritorio":3},
                "ticket4":{"numero":1, "escritorio":4},
        }
        var [ ticket1, ticket2, ticket3, ticket4 ] = payload;
```

A todo momento me dice

```
var [ ticket1, ticket2, ticket3, ticket4 ] = payload;
                                             ^ TypeError: payload is not iterable
```

Muchas gracias de antemano

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La forma en la que estás tratando de convertir el objeto es erróneo. Estoy entendiendo que lo que necesitas es almacenar los valores de los tickets en las posiciones del array. Si es eso lo que buscas puedes usar esto:

```
[ ticket1, ticket2, ticket3, ticket4 ] = Object.values(payload);
```

Ahora si lo que buscas es usar esos mismos valores usando sus mismas claves puedes usar:

```
{ ticket1, ticket2, ticket3, ticket4 } = payload;
```